# Retain editability upon replacing contentEditable element with ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, cross-browser, contenteditable

## Background

Trying to edit an ordered list using a content editable `<div>`. Looking to paste any content, type any content, or delete any content, and always display at least one ordered list item, but never any other types of text (e.g., no blank lines, no quoted text, no indentation, no fonts from Microsoft Word, and so on).

Using jQuery 1.9.1 to support as many browsers as possible. The [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuJ7N/) has the source code below.

## Code

The JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.directions > ol').prop('contentEditable','true');
  $('.directions > ol').keydown( function( e ) {
    // Prevent shift-enter from creating blank lines.
    if( e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $('body').on( 'focus', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data( 'before', $this.html() );
    return $this;
  }).on( 'paste blur input keyup', '[contenteditable]', function( e ) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if( $this.data('before') !== $this.html() ) {
      $this.data( 'before', $this.html() );
      $this.trigger( 'change' );
    }
  });

  $('.directions > ol').on( 'change', function( e ) {
    var fragment = $(this).clone();
    fragment.find( 'br' ).replaceWith( "\n" );
    var div = document.createElement( 'div' );
    var text = fragment.text().replace( /[\r\n]+/g, '\n' );
    text = '<ol><li>' + text.replace( /\n/g, '</li><li>' ) + '</li></ol>';
    $(this).replaceWith( text );
  });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="directions">
  <ol>
    <li>Turn left onto 5th Street after 500m.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/list.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Problem

When the contenteditable `<ol>` is replaced:

```
$(this).replaceWith( text );
```

the following event bindings are dropped:

```
$('.directions > ol').prop('contentEditable','true');
.on( 'paste blur input keyup', '[contenteditable]', function( e ) {
```

## Questions

My primary question is: How would you replace the inner `<ol>` contents without destroying the `contenteditable` bindings -- so that the user can continue to edit the contents, even if they select the entire text to replace it?

My secondary question is: is this even a viable approach? I researched [various WYSIWYG implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor#Implementations). They all seem quite complex and have a giant footprint (except for [Whizzywing](http://whizzywing.com/)) for such a seemingly simple task.

Comment: That the various WYSIWYG editors are that complex is due the still existing bugs/inconsistencies in the implementation of `contenteditable` in the different browsers/versions. While I personally would prefer not to use such libraries, I was faced with these bugs so many times that I went to choose an editor, living with its huge code footprint.

Comment: @t.niese: Sadly, I am tempted to agree. Firefox has an unfixed bug reported two years ago regarding backspace not deleting list items. What editor did you choose for your project?

Comment: I used TinyMCE while CKEditor was pre 4. But migrated to CKEditor since the version 4 was released (other editors where/are still disappointing). While I don't like that in both the GUI is tightly glued to the features, CKEditor was easier to customize and it evolves faster into the direction of my needs (robust inline editing, shared toolbar spaces and with 4.3 (beta) widgets). TinyMCE seems to be always one step behind CKEditor. A downside of CKEditor 4 is that it currently does not support to wrap `a` elements around _block_ elements. But personally I think it is currently the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can have unintended side effects like this. Sometimes it works better just to use regular JavaScript, even if there is a jQuery shortcut.

I tested this in the jsfiddle posted above. Replace the line:

```
$(this).replaceWith( text );
```

with

```
document.getElementById(this).innerHTML = text;
```

I tried using the jQuery .html() command, and it didn't remove the bindings, but it did keep moving the text cursor to the beginning of the line.

UPDATE: tested in Chrome 29, Firefox 24 and IE9. Works great in all.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, there are still a number of paste bugs in Firefox (on Ubuntu). I think trimming down the CKEditor is probably the way to go.